# Using useState and setting a class accordingly in React

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and Material UI and I want to die. That being said, I would like to accomplish two things.

- I would like to set a boolean state
- I would like to highlight a row by setting a class based on the boolean

If I was in vanilla, what I would do is set a variable and toggle a class. With React I seem to need to look through documentation and API to set a bool and set a class. I am in someone else's code so I figured I could learn from them, but. Yeah.

So basically there is a component like so

```
return (
  <XGrid 
     someAttributes={stuff}
     someOther={morestuff}
     onContextMenu={(event) => handleContextMenu(event)}
  />
)
```

With some stuff like this

```
const [rowHighlighted, setRowHighlighted] = React.useState(false);

const handleContextMenu = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => 
{
   // Me trying to do anything :D 
   setRowHighlighted(!rowHighlighted)
   // This is always false no matter what
   console.log(rowHighlighted);
   // How can this be done the React way? Especially we don't render the Material UI rows manually 
   // there's no prop or attribute for me to set, so mix in some vanilla? Will I get fired :P
   // Also do I really seriously have to convince TS that these things exist?
   cell!.parentElement!.parentElement!.classList.toggle('selectedRow', rowHighlighted);
}
```

Comment: Setting state in React is asynchronous, your `console.log` is occurring before the value has changed. To wait for the state to change, you can look into "Effects" ([docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html))

Comment: You really don't want to manually modify class names (while you might not get fired, whoever needs to touch your code later will have to resort to alcohol). Have you looked at e.g. https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/selection/ ?

Comment: @AKX I am on drink 3 or 4 already, why did they need to reinvent the wheel into a 10 dimension hyper cube. Anyway, I need a right click/contextmenu to highlight the row so the selection bit does not work out for me.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there.

Instead of accessing the DOM to toggle the class

```js
cell!.parentElement!.parentElement!.classList.toggle('selectedRow', rowHighlighted);
```

The react way to do this is to set the class conditionally during render. For example

```
return <YourParentParentElement className={rowHighlighted ? 'selectedRow' : ''} />
```

Comment: And what if this is a Material UI component (XGrid). I don't have control over the rows so I need to select via the element I do have control over which is a `Box`. The `Box` is inside a MUI column which is inside a MUI row, etc..

Comment: You can customise the classes listed there https://material-ui.com/api/x-grid/#css they also provide some links at the end of the section to help to customise the components.

Comment: Right - but I don't need to customize, I need to add a new functionality that on rightclick/contextmenu, the row is highlighted. How can I do this in React if I'm not the one controlling the element (ie I didn't write the render function)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here the the useState hook triggers a rerender of your component. That's the reason `rowHighlighted` has always the initial values which is `false`. This [article](https://dev.to/alexkhismatulin/update-boolean-state-right-with-react-hooks-3k2i) solves and describes your problem pretty well. I'm sure you can solve and understand the problem by following the instruction in the article.